# Send an email with SMTP in Python

Tags: python, email, crash, smtp, smtplib

I'm working on a project of making my own Instant-Messaging program, even without graphics or anything, just to get to know the built-in modules in python.
Here, I tried to write a code that the user will input the username and password the user wants, and then a e-mail will be sent (to the user), that will contain a 12-character random string, and the user will input it back to the program. Somehow, when I run the code my whole computer freezes!
Here's the code:

```
import smtplib
SMTPServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
SMTPServer.starttls()
SMTPServer.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)*

userEmail = raw_input("Please enter your e-mail: ")
if verifyEmail(userEmail) == False:
    while True:
        userEmail = raw_input("Error! Please enter your e-mail: ")
        if verifyEmail(userEmail) == True:
            break

randomString = generateRandomString()
message = """From: From Person <%s>
To: To Person <%s>
Subject: Ido's IM Program Registration

Your registration code is: %s
""" %(SERVEREMAIL, userEmail, randomString)

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
   smtpObj.sendmail(SERVEREMAIL, userEmail, message)
   print "Successfully sent email"
except smtplib.SMTPException:
   print "Error: unable to send email"

inputString = raw_input("Input generated code sent: ")
```

Comment: You go to the trouble of setting up an SMTP connection with Gmail, then don't use it to send your e-mail. Instead you create a new SMTP connection with `localhost` and use that. Are you actually running a mail server on the computer that you're running this script on?

Comment: I must have misunderstood the way the SMTP works, Do you mean I should just delete `smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')` and change the next row to `SMTPServer.sendmail(SERVEREMAIL, userEmail, message)`, because I have already created the server when I wrote `SMTPServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)` ?

Comment: Unless you're actually running an SMTP server on the same computer as the script, that sounds like a good thing to try.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example of a smtp client.
where does your code block?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


class SMTPClient(object):
    def __init__(self, recepient, subject, body):
        self.recepient = recepient
        self.subject = subject
        self.body = body
        self.mail_host = conf.get('smtp_server.host')
        self.mail_port = conf.get('smtp_server.port')
        self.username = conf.get('account.username')
        self.password = conf.get('account.password')
        self.mail_sender = conf.get('account.from')
        self._setup()

    def _setup(self):
        self.smtp_client = smtplib.SMTP(self.mail_host, self.mail_port)
        self.smtp_client.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
        self.smtp_client.starttls()
        self.smtp_client.login(self.username, self.password)
        self._send_mail()

    def _make_mail(self):
        message = MIMEText(self.body, _charset='utf-8')
        message['From'] = self.mail_sender
        message['To'] = self.recepient
        message['Subject'] = self.subject
        return message.as_string()

    def send_mail(self):
        self.smtp_client.sendmail(self.mail_sender, self.recepient, self._make_mail())
        self.smtp_client.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me!

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email import Encoders

gmail_user = 'example@hotmail.com'
gmail_pwd = 'somepassword'
subject = 'HEY'
text = 'Some text here'

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = gmail_user
msg['To'] = gmail_user
msg['Subject'] = subject

msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')

Encoders.encode_base64(part)

mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.live.com", 587)
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.starttls()
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
mailServer.sendmail(gmail_user,gmail_user, msg.as_string())
mailServer.close()
```